# How to use javascript to prompt based on room availability?

Tags: php, function, onload, prompt

I'm new to programming and I need help on my code.  I want my page to prompt me if there will be available rooms left.  I'm using the onload function on the admin page.

so far here is my code

```
function prompt()
{
< ?php 
include("dbconfig.php");

$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rooms WHERE status = 'available'";
$result = @mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not execute query");

?> 
if(< ?php $result <= 14 ?>){
 alert("Rooms left: < ?php echo $result ?>");
 }

else{
 alert("Welcome Admin.");
 } 
}

window.onload=prompt;
```

edit:

The code worked fine now but it displays "Resource id#4", not the value of the count.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are confused about where PHP processes vs. where Javascript processes.

PHP is processed on the **server side**, while Javascript is processed on the **client side**. Think of it like this...

1. You access a page.
2. Your PHP is processed, and the final output is sent to the browser.
3. Your Javascript is processed by the browser.

As you have it now, you'd be getting some funny output... especially because of your lack of **echo** statements. Here is what you'd probably be seeing in your browser page source:

```
function prompt()
{
if(){
 alert("Rooms left: < ?php echo $result ?>");
 }
else{
 alert("Welcome Admin.");
 } 
}

window.onload=prompt;
```

Notice the empty **if statement** (also the space in the start tags:

```
if(<?php echo ($result <= 14); ?>){
 alert("Rooms left: <?php echo $result ?>");
 }
```

This should make your Javascript evaluate a boolean true/false. Don't forget that Javascript needs to be wrapped in a < script > tag too!

***To answer your MySQL question...***
Try it like this:

```
//We can alias the COUNT(*) as MyCount for easy reference
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) as MyCount FROM rooms WHERE status = 'available'";
$result = @mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not execute query");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result); //$row is now an array and will now have your count in it
echo $row['MyCount']; //This will print the count from the database. You could use it in other ways as well.
```

Comment: thank you so much sir ! ive got the code working but it displays "Resource id#4" ?

Comment: That's related to what the other people have said about MySQL. Your variable contains a result resource instead the actual records. Since you only have 1 record in this case (the count) you only have to read one row instead of looping the results. I will edit the answer above to show how it should be done. Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

I feel you can't mix php with js codes.
php is mainly on server side , while the js is client side
from the snippet you provide, maybe you should use purely php as follows:

```
< ?php 
    include("dbconfig.php");
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM rooms WHERE status = 'available'"; 
    $result = @mysql_query($sql) or die("Could not execute query");
    if ($result <= 14) {
        echo("Rooms left: $result");
    }
    else {
        echo("Welcome Admin.")
    }
 ?>
```

This should be run at the first when request

Comment: This is correct too. You can mix them, you just have to be conscious of the context that they run in. Throws a lot of new people for a loop.

Comment: yes it true also , thank you very much for the reply. but when i run it, it displays "Resource id #4" ?

Answer (score 0):

`mysql_query` returns resource, not a result.
Try to use:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `rooms` WHERE `status` = 'available'";
$res = @mysql_query($sql) or die('Could not execute query');
$count = mysql_result($res, 0, 0);
```

Answer (score 0):

There should be no space in php tags:

```
< ?php 
 ^
```

Should be:

```
<?php
```

You are also missing a **fetching** function, here is how you can get row count in a variable:

```
<?php $count = mysql_num_rows($result);?>
```

Later you can use the `$count` variable in the `if` condition.

Comment: sir it displays "Resource id #4" ? not the number of available rooms left ?

Comment: @renz: No one is sir here :) Make sure that `$result` is assigned to `mysql_query` function and your query runs successfully.

Comment: oh i think i have a problem on count ? it always displays 1 even i i have lot of rooms left.

Comment: @renz: Modify your sql query like this: `SELECT * FROM rooms WHERE status = 'available'`. Now it will return total count :)

Answer (score 0):

use [mysql_fetch_row](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php) , and after that in the condition , compare to $row[0]

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `rooms` WHERE `status` = 'available'";
$res = @mysql_query($sql) or die('Could not execute query');

$row = mysql_fetch_row($res);

if(< ?php $row[0] <= 14 ?>){
```